# How to show both simple and extended label both in 3d pie chart using JFreeChart & JasperSoft

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am a bit new to JFreeChart and I had a requirement of showing both simple and extended labels on 3d pie chart using JFreeChart java library & JasperSoft i.e percentage labels on top of the sections of 3d pie chart as simple labels and the key on adjacent sections as an extended label.

I am able to achieve either one of the labels at a time by using the below code snippet.

> setSimpleLabels(true) - lable on top of the section
>
> setSimpleLabels(false) - lable on adjacent of the section

How to achieve both the label's designs in one single 3d pie chart as shown below in the image?
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: As these are mutually exclusive, why not both key _&_ percent on one label, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36830243/230513); more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3551238/230513)?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had done that key and percentage in a label. But, I have a requirement of displaying the key as extended label and percentage as simple label. So, looking for a way to do that.

Comment: You could try a custom implementation of `drawPie()`.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could share a code snippet for the custom label in drawPie().

Comment: I cited label samples [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68876506/how-to-show-both-simple-and-extended-label-both-in-3d-pie-chart-using-jfreechart#comment121725975_68876506); although untested, I was looking at changing [this](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/09e374f617c3a5c2e68d260f17a03f1e3f584121/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.java#L2281) to draw both; I'm guessing you'd have to work out a way to render two different label, too.